# Sign In using ADFS in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I am developing an app using Ionic 6 and Capacitor 3. I want the users to authenticate using ADFS. We have an on-premise ADFS server and I am trying to set up the relying party trust for the SSO.

In RPT we need to provide the callback URL which should be https.

I tried using the following package for OATH2:

https://github.com/moberwasserlechner/capacitor-oauth2

As per the above package, the return URL is of localhost which will not work with ADFS. Since the Ionic Apps run on mobile they will not be hosted on any server (Frontend part). So we cannot have a return URL of the frontend.

Another approach I can try is using the passport saml library in the backend using Node. But ADFS opens its own page for authentication. I am not getting how to pass data between frontend and backend and vice versa. In Capacitor 3 I am not getting the appUrlOpen events which I can listen for URL change. Also the browserPageLoaded, browserFinished gets fired but these do not return any data.

Is there any other approach? We cannot use miniOrnage or Auth Connect as the app is internal and will not be shared publically.